# ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6, 1]

Tags: python, scikit-learn, metrics, multiclass-classification, precision-recall

I'm breaking through an image classification button.
I would like to calculate the precision and recall for each image.
Currently for each image I have two .txt: one that indicates the GT and one that indicates the detection.
Example:

```
GT: [59, 59, 59]
DETECTION: [30, 30, 1]
```

How do I calculate metrics if the length of the GT is less than or greater than the length of the detection?

```
GT: [64, 64, 64, 64, 64]
DETECTION: [34]
```

or

```
GT: [59, 59, 59]
PRED: [30, 30, 1, 59]
```

I tried using this function: `precision = precision_score(GT, DETECTION, average = 'macro'`) but when `len(GT)` is different from `len(DETECTION)` it can't calculate the metrics...

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [6, 1]
```

Anyone know how to help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: You should have a predicted and an actual image label (ground truth), shouldn't you? Do you allow multi-labels? In that case, you should have a 1-out-of-K array for each image.

Comment: it is a multiclass tast.
For each actual image I have one or more numbers that indicate the class of the bounding box detected.
In detection, however, it happens that my model detects less or more bounding boxes. So if I try to calculate the metrics, sklearn returns me a valueError. This is because they don't have the same number of elements.
PS: each name of the class of a bounding box is associated with a name in a json file.

Comment: My question is: can I calculate metrics on a classification task when `len (gt)> len (pred)`? `example gt = ["apple", "cat", "rabbit"], pred = ["apple", "rabbit"]`

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to use an array that has the same shape in both cases. For instance, if you have K classes, then both vectors should have shape (1, K). Then the values is either 0 or 1, depending if the class is present or not. [You have to encode the categories.](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features)

Comment: I got it! Thank you @gtancev